# How to interpret quadratic effects?

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, interpretation

I have built a LMM (using LME4) for understanding how investment fund's structural characteristics (things like how much debt they have, their size etc) impacts upon performance.

In the analysis, I included the variable GAV (which denotes size in USD$), I have also included a quadratic term for GAV to evaluate if size beyond a certain point impacts a fund's performance.

I get the following outputs for the GAV values:

-0.067(GAV) + 0.076(GAV²)

This leads me to believe size has a positive impact upon performance and those larger funds will perform better. However, when I graph GAV's quadratic effect in R, I get the following output: 
[image: GAV Quadratic Effect]

I don't understand why it appears to invert at approx. $5bn. I have researched online and it seems that to have a quadratic effects graph that increases up to a point and then starts decreasing requires the squared term to be negative and the original (non-squared term in this instance just GAV) to be positive?

I'm very lost and any help would be really appreciated! Thank you.

Also please ignore the title "European Open End Gearing Quadratic Effects" the was copied over from another graph and the title hasn't been updated.

Comment: I'm skeptical of this graph. When you put in 2.5 billion into the regression equation, you don't get ~.05. There's something missing here that will prevent us from helping you. Are there other variables in the model? How did you get this plot?

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for helping. For some reason unbeknown to me, I forgot to mention I also transformed GAV with a natural log + 1. So (log(GAV+1). Sorry for not clarifying that. Additionally, I have included quite a few other variables for levels of debt, country focus and economic covariates.  I'm a bit of a novice to be honest, so apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you for these details. How did you make this plot?

Comment: No worries Noah, I used R and the LME4 package.

Comment: But which function?

Comment: Apologies - I used: ggplot(panel, aes(x=GAV, y=ExcessReturn,)) + 
stat_smooth(method='lm', formula=y~poly(x,2))+ 
ggtitle("European GAV Quadratic Effects ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely has a few advanced and potentially esoteric aspects, but based on your comments I think I can explain what you're seeing but also why you should rethink your plot.

First, the graph is plotting a curve whose coefficients are based on a regression of `ExcessReturn` only on `GAV` and it's square. The coefficients in this model will be different from the model you're trying to draw your substantive conclusions from, which, as you said, contains other covariates and presumably some random effects. So this plot is totally unrelated to your model.

Second, if you're using `poly(x, 2)`, the coefficients you are estimating are not the ones you would get if you modeled `y ~ x + x^2`. This is because the default for `poly()` is to create orthogonal polynomials, which are transformations of your variables and their powers. To get coefficients that you could interpret in a standard way, in your `glmer` call, either use `ExcessReturn ~ GAV + I(GAV^2) + var1 + var2` or `ExcessReturn ~ poly(GAV, 2, raw = TRUE) + var1 + var2`. Those are the coefficients you'll want to report in your output.